# What is the most efficient way to parse and manipulate large JSON files in Python?

Tags: python, json, performance, memory-management

I am working on a project where I need to parse and manipulate large JSON files in Python. However, I'm having trouble finding an efficient way to handle these files, as they are several gigabytes in size and I'm experiencing performance issues. I've tried using the built-in json library, but it seems to be slow and memory-intensive. Can anyone recommend a more efficient way to handle large JSON files in Python? Ideally, I would like to be able to load and manipulate only the parts of the file that I need, without having to read the entire file into memory. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have already tried using the built-in json library in Python to parse and manipulate large JSON files, but it turned out to be slow and memory-intensive. Specifically, I used the json.load() method to read the entire file into memory and then worked with the resulting Python object. However, this approach did not scale well with the size of the file and caused performance issues.

What I was hoping for was a more efficient way to handle large JSON files in Python, where I could load and manipulate only the parts of the file that I need, without having to read the entire file into memory. I am open to using third-party libraries or other tools, as long as they can offer better performance and scalability. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: JSON is not a good way to store large amounts of data for precisely the reasons you've discovered.

Comment: Maybe try `jq` in your Terminal/shell to see if it can extract the parts you need fast enough and if so maybe you can call it via `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Try ijson.

If you are strictly bound to use JSON, then your only choice would be ijson.

https://pypi.org/project/ijson/

I was able to parse multi-gigabytes single JSON file, while using memory below 1 gigabyte.

It could be a bit tough, though, depending on the JSON file structure. You may try it by yourself first, and there are plenty of questions regarding practical use of ijson available in Stack Overflow.

But if I were you, I may tend to use JSONL format, to scale with tools such as pyspark.